# Choosing display for fullscreen in Qt/QML

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qml

is there a (better multiplatform) way how to choose on which display should Qt/QML application show when going fullscreen? I can switch primary display ~/.config/monitors.xml on Ubuntu, but this will affect other programs too, so better something in QT? 
Thanks.

```
ApplicationWindow {
  ..
  visible: true
  visibility: "FullScreen"
  ..
}
```

Comment: visibility is not string property. It have to be `Window.FullScreen` in your case.

Comment: Both variants are fine and working. Maybe yours is faster.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's impossible in pure `QML`. But you can try some C++ extension:

```
class ScreenManager : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ScreenManager(QObject *parent = 0);
    Q_INVOKABLE int screenCount() const {
        return QGuiApplication::screens().count();
    }
    Q_INVOKABLE void setScreen(QWindow * window, int screen) {
        if(screen >= 0 && screen < QGuiApplication::screens().count())
            window->setScreen(QGuiApplication::screens().at(screen));
    }
};
```

You can expose the object to `QML` as a singleton or standalone item.

and so use it in QML:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log(screenManager.screenCount());
        screenManager.setScreen(mainWindow,1); // for a second screen
    }

    ScreenManager {
        id: screenManager
    }
}
```

But currently I have to computer with more the 1 screen so I didn't test the code.

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04 screenManager.screenCount() is returning 2 and window->screen()->name() is returning the right display after the switch, however the app remains all the time at screen 0. Maybe Ubuntu bug?

Answer (score 0):

It works only if you show it without fullScreen mode.